# Entering plist data to core data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, plist

I currently have a plist file that contains 27 achievements data and i'm trying to enter it into the core data entity know as achievement as seen below

```
func createAchievements() {

    let A:Achievement = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Achievement", into: CoreDatabaseContoller.getContext()) as! Achievement

    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Achievement", ofType: "plist")
    let Items = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath!) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

        for item in Items {

            A.theName = item["Name"] as! String
            A.theDescription = item["Description"] as! String
            A.theImage = item["Image"] as! String
            A.aAmount = item["Amount"] as! NSNumber
            A.aNeededAmount = item["NeededAmount"] as! NSNumber                  //DOESN'T WORK IT ONLY SHOWS OR PUTS IN THE LAST ONE.
            A.aStage = item["Stage"] as! NSNumber
            A.aReward = item["Reward"] as! NSNumber
            A.aHasBeenAchieved = item["HasBeenAchieved"] as! NSNumber
            A.theSearchName = item["SearchName"] as! String

            CoreDatabaseContoller.saveContext()

        }
}
```

But when I load up the game and the achievements menu part of the game that displays the achievements all the images and text that are supposed to be filled by core data are not there and the images are red Xs except the last achievement in the achievement menu which seems to be working properly as seen inn the picture below

[image]

I originally entered the data from the achievements through a switch system that looked horrible in my code as seen below and it worked not problem. But now for some reason when I try and enter it from a plist to core data it seems to not work

func giveDataForAchievements() {

```
    if achievementsGenerated == false {

        for count in 1...24 {

            var aName = "None"
            var aDesc = "None"
            var aImage = "locked"
            var aAmount:NSNumber = 0
            var aNeededAmount:NSNumber = 1
            var aStage:NSNumber = 0
            var aReward:NSNumber = 0
            var aHasbeenAchieved:NSNumber = 0
            var aSearchName = ""

            switch count {

            case 1:

                aName = "DAILY"
                aDesc = "Daily Achievement"
                aImage = "locked"
                aAmount = 0
                aNeededAmount = 1
                aStage = 0
                aReward = 350
                aHasbeenAchieved = 0
                aSearchName = "Ach0"

            case 2:

                aName = "DAILY"
                aDesc = "Daily Achievement"
                aImage = "locked"
                aAmount = 0
                aNeededAmount = 1
                aStage = 0
                aReward = 350
                aHasbeenAchieved = 0
                aSearchName = "Ach1"

            case 3:

                aName = "DAILY"
                aDesc = "Daily Achievement"
                aImage = "locked"
                aAmount = 0
                aNeededAmount = 1
                aStage = 0
                aReward = 350
                aHasbeenAchieved = 0
                aSearchName = "Ach2"

            case 4:

                aName = "ROOKIE"
                aDesc = "Finish the tutorial level"
                aImage = "locked"
                aAmount = 0
                aNeededAmount = 1
                aStage = 2
                aReward = 350
                aHasbeenAchieved = 0
                aSearchName = "Ach3"


     createAchievements(aName: aName, Des: aDesc, Image: aImage, Amount: aAmount, Needed: aNeededAmount, Stage: aStage, Reward: aReward, BeenAchieved: aHasbeenAchieved, SearchName: aSearchName)

           // all the way to 27
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the same managed object multiple times.  Move the line:

```
let A:Achievement = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Achievement", into: CoreDatabaseContoller.getContext()) as! Achievement
```

into the for loop.  It will then create a new object for each Item.